# Are our gut microbes responsible for 50-90% of our behaviour-regulating neuro-transmittors?

Tags: medical-science, biology, neurology

I have always concidered this channel serious, but they are making very bold claims.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3Ftj5E90tY

> 50% of our dopamine and 90% of our serotonin is created by microbes in
>   our guts.

Is this true and could someone put this into context? Like, what's the difference in a person if they have half the dopamine and 1/10th of the serotonin? Would this be the effect if you removed the microbes?

Comment: I think the last question is not a skeptical one (but still an interesting question).  Should we mod that out, or maybe leave it in as a bonus question?

Comment: It must be noted that even if the gut microflora produced 90% of the body serotonin, it doesn't mean that removing the gut microflora results in 90% decrease in the amount of serotonin the body has. It might up its own production instead.

Comment: @JasonR I think all skeptisicm must be put in context, they do not claim that in the video, but the video is refering to the stomach as the second brain, so I think it's important to understand weather the information they are providing is supporting that claim.

Comment: @JanDvorak that's what I'm thinking, but I have no idea...